# grails service hierarchy

Tags: grails, service

Let's say I have 10 grails services.  Each one of these services will be making calls to a REST service.  So, I'd like to encapsulate the REST code so it can be easily resused by the 10 services.

In considering options, I could:

1) create another service or bean with REST related code and inject it every one of the 10 services.
2) create a superclass service containing the REST code and have all 10 grails services extend this class.

I'm trying to go with option 2, but running into problems with dependency injection into the superclass.

Example:

```
class SuperService {
   def aString 
}

class ExampleService extends SuperService {
}
```

resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    superService(SuperService) {
        aString = "something"
    }
    exampleService(ExampleService) {
    }
}
```

When I run this in an debugger while running an integration test, I see the value of aString is null.  Obviously, that's going to be problematic for me.

As you might expect, running the same code with following resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    superService(SuperService) {
    }
    exampleService(ExampleService) {
        aString = "something"
    }
}
```

and aString = "something".

So, I prefer option 2 because it will be less configuration wiring, but I don't think it's going to be feasible approach.  In other words, there's no value if I have to set aString in each one of the subclasses.

Thoughts?

Am I missing something?

I'm open to other options as well.

Thanks in advance,
Todd

Comment: Why do you think option 2 will be less configuration wiring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea with option #2 in terms of being DRY -- but it's really just one line. If the only thing in common with the superService object is the service, and no other methods, then you're really not saving yourself any work. If anything, just declaring a super class for a dependency injection makes things more hidden and possibly harder to maintain.

It sounded like your proposing putting the REST methods in the superService, so not sure why you're concerned about dependency injection into the superService -- you'd want your methods there to perform the REST interactions that and subclass would be able to call. Or are you attempting a combination of options 1 and 2?

Comment: In the superService, I need access to springSecurityService or one of the util or holder objects provided by Spring Security plugin.  This superSerivce needs to know who is logged in before making the rest calls.  On Friday, I couldn't get this superService to retrieve anything... always NPE when using security.  I think my issue is with dependency injection.

Comment: Well, this morning, the following code is working in the superClass:        def ctx = AH.application.mainContext
      SpringSecurityService springSecurityService = ctx.springSecurityService
      def loggedInUser = springSecurityService.getPrincipal()

Comment: Interesting. I'm still surprised the injection didn't work into superService. Are you using Grails 2.0.RC1? Or 1.3.7?